# Javascript event that reloads the page, is getting called when the page is refreshed, making a infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The problem does not occur in the first load but only when the event is called by reordering the column, after that reload it's called automatically.

```
  tabelaProdutos.on('column-reorder', function(e, settings, details) {
    ...
    location.reload();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A better explanation of what you want to happen and what else you have tried would be necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: I want to save the column order in the database and after that refresh the page.
I've tried location.reload(true); to remove cash, but it didn't work.